# grunt-contrib-jasmine can't find PhantomJS API?

Tags: phantomjs, gruntjs

The PhantomJS API claims to allow access to 'fs' and a few other built-in commonJS modules through the standard require interface. grunt-contrib-jasmine claims to run all specs using phantomJS. But when I use grunt-contrib-jasmine the require method doesn't seem to be available?

```
fs = require('fs')
describe 'DesignService',  ->
  it 'test loadFromJSON',  ->
    jsonFile = fs.read("resources/sample_pole.json")
```

Gives me the error:

```
 ReferenceError: Can't find variable: require at
>> target/spec/Spec.js:3
```

What am I doing wrong?

In case it isn't clear, I am compiling from coffeescript, and then pointing the grunt-contrib-jasmine to the output of the compilation. The other specs are all running fine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Cause

`require` method is only available on *server* side (Nodejs/PhantomJS), but all jasmine tests (specs) are executed on the *client side*.

### Possible solution

You could create a JavaScript file in `helpers` folder with the content like this:

```
window.jsonFile = { some : json_object }
```

And use a `jsonFile` reference in your spec files.

### Explanation

From the [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) description:

> PhantomJS is a headless WebKit scriptable with a JavaScript API.

From [grunt-contrib-jasmine](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-jasmine) description:

> Run jasmine specs headlessly through PhantomJS.

`grunt-contrib-jasmine` is automatically creating `_SpecRunner.html` file (see below for example) with all user specs and passing it to the PhantomJS. PhantomJS is a separate executable, that in Nodejs is only wrapped as a package. This is the same executable as if downloaded from [Phantomjs.org](http://phantom.org) page.

In the end this line is executed: `.\node_modules\grunt-contrib-jasmine\node_modules\grunt-lib-phantomjs\node_modules\phantomjs\lib\phantom\phantomjs .\node_modules\grunt-contrib-jasmine\node_modules\grunt-lib-phantomjs\phantomjs\main.js .\_SpecRunner.html`. 
Here `main.js` file is to open the page and bind alerts (`alert(jsonString)`) that are thrown to the grunt logging.

**So PhantomJS API is available in `main.js`, but not in `_SpecRunner.html` and jasmine spec files.**

The result is the same as if opened `_SpecRunner.html` with the browser, except all messages will be intercepted by jasmine reporter and displayed on screen.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Jasmine Spec Runner</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href=".grunt/grunt-contrib-jasmine/jasmine.css">

  <!-- Jasmine test suite -->
  <script src="./.grunt/grunt-contrib-jasmine/jasmine.js"></script>
  <script src="./.grunt/grunt-contrib-jasmine/jasmine-html.js"></script>

  <!-- Some vendor libraries -->
  <script src="./test/vendor/jquery.js"></script>

  <!-- Some helpers -->
  <script src="./test/helpers/ts.js"></script>

  <!-- Your spec files -->
  <script src="./test/main_spec.js"></script>

  <!-- Jasmine reporter that displays the result-->    
  <script src="./.grunt/grunt-contrib-jasmine/reporter.js"></script>  
  <script src="./.grunt/grunt-contrib-jasmine/jasmine-helper.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: So you're saying that the PhantomJS API is available for node packages *using* Phantom, but not from within scripts running in Phantom. Is that correct? I had previously interpreted this that Phantom had *added* support for require/fs/etc in their JS engine to make testing easier. I will try the helper fix.

Comment: PhantomJS is a separate executable, and in Nodejs paskage it is only wrapped. You can examine it in `\node_modules\grunt-contrib-jasmine\node_modules\grunt-lib-phantomjs\node_modules\phantomjs\lib\phantom`, this is the same package as if you downloaded it from Phantomjs.og page. You can imagine, that in the end this line is executed: `phantomjs jasmine.js ./_SpecRunner.html`, so PhantomJS API is available in `jasmine.js`, but not in `_SpecRunner.html`.

Comment: Ah, I've got you. Thanks.

Comment: Here is a little example how can you write modular tests and use phantomjs for testing https://github.com/mikach/phantomjs-test-runner Hope it will be useful for you.